# where is unique memcache key prefix?

Tags: drupal-7, memcached

I have installed memcached and drupal module memcache and in linux command line :

```
-bash-4.1# netstat -tap | grep memcached
```

tcp        0      0 *:memcache                  *:*                         LISTEN      8431/memcached
tcp        0      0 *:memcache                  *:*                         LISTEN      8431/memcached

Seems like it is listening to IP and Port but now the part where I get it to work with drupal 7.18 so I can see what is going on?

Following these instruction:

```php
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';
$conf['memcache_key_prefix'] = 'something_unique';

 /* note : Replace the "something_unique" in the last line with your own unique memcache key prefix. */
```

Where do I find "your own unique memcache key prefix"?

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1131468) for the module says:

> If you want to have multiple Drupal installations share memcached instances, you need to include a unique prefix for each Drupal installation in the $confarray of settings.php:
>
> ```
> $conf['memcache_key_prefix'] = 'something_unique';
> ```

You need that parameter only if you have more than one Drupal installation using the same memcached instance; in the case there is just a Drupal installation, you don't need it.
As long as you use a different value for each Drupal installation, you can use the value you want. You could also use the domain name (including the sub-domain name).